# How to .indexOf on two chars?

Tags: java

So, I'm trying to make a calculator that respects multiplications and divisions order, I'm typing a String, for example "6+43/2-5*12" and my program should find the first division or multiplication position.

I can find the first multiplication on the String like:

```
int first_mult = string.indexOf('*');
```

And the first division the String like:

```
int first_div = string.indexOf('/');
```

That works, but I want to find the first multiplication or division at same time, I've tryed:

```
int first_oper = string.indexOf('*'||'/');
```

But that don't works. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: You can find `first_mult` and you can find `first_div`. Why don't you compare them and get the smallest 0 or positive number of the two?

Comment: So you are trying to make the precedence of calculation and compute the higher priority first? Also, as I understand it, you want to find their indexes to calculate them first?

Comment: @forpas thats what i'm doing until now

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: @forpas probably beacause I made it wrong, but that dont works when I don't use at least one division or multiplication, because it compares number with null.

Comment: indexOf() does not return null when the char is not found. It returns -1. You have a very simple case here that you want to change to a more complicated one.

Comment: @forpas oh didn't know that, thanks, will try it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use an `IntStream`:

```
int first_oper = IntStream.range(0, string.length())
    .filter(i -> string.charAt(i) == '*' || string.charAt(i) == '/')
    .findFirst()
    .orElse(-1);
```

Or, of course, use a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < string.length(); ++i) {
  switch (string.charAt(i)) {
    case '*': case '/': return i;
  }
}
return -1;
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this using [`Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html).  For example:

```
public int indexOfOperator(final String string) {
    final Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[*/]").matcher(string);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
        return -1;
    }

    return matcher.start();
}
```

Obviously improvements can be made such as storing the compiled [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) somewhere sensible.

Comment: So the matcher returns the first found char in the string based off of the regex?

Comment: @Compilerv2: It returns the _index_ of the first found char in the string based off of the regex.

Answer (score -1):

```
you can try this one also.

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "6+43/2-5*12";
    String[] process = { "/", "*" };

    Map<String, Stack<Integer>> values = findWords(process, string);

    System.out.println(values.toString());
}

public static Map<String, Stack<Integer>> findWords(
        String[] process, String phrase) {
    Map<String, Stack<Integer>> values = new HashMap<>();

    for (String pro : process) {
        Stack<Integer> indexs = new Stack<>();

        for (int i = -1; (i = phrase.indexOf(pro, i + 1)) != -1;) {
            indexs.add(i);
        }

        values.put(pro, indexs);
    }

    return values;
}
```